# Same script is giving result zero on cron where manually getting correct result

Tags: bash, count, cron, find

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /ad/bd/cd/dd/ed/zd
count=$(find . -type f|cut -d "/" -f3|wc -l)
echo $count >> /ad/bd/cd/abc.log
#exit
```

Manually it is giving correct value. i.e 230

- - - - - ad/bd/script

when above cron running it is giving zero i.e 0

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying absolute path of the directory in `find` where you want to look for files

```
count=$(find "/ad/bd/cd/dd/ed/zd" -type f | cut -d "/" -f3 | wc -l)
```

In general, `cron` runs your commands in your home directory. If you want to run your script from a specific directory, start that shell snippet by a command to change the directory like this:

```
0 10 * * * cd /some/dir && /path/to/script args
```

Please note that, the use of `&&` over `;` doesn’t make any difference, but if the `cd` command fails (for instance, because of the target directory doesn’t exist) with `&&` your script is not executed, whereas with `;` it's executed (but in an unintended directory).